# Find SubModel instance when querying Base Model with Django

Tags: django, django-models

Considering the following models :

```
class Content(models.Model):
    ...

class ContentText(Content):
    ...

class ContentRichText(Content):
    ...
```

When querying Base model :

```
listContent = Content.objects.all()

for content in listContent:
    #if content is ContentText:
        #do stuff
    #elif content is ContentRichText:
        #do other stuff
```

Is there a proper method to determine instance type when querying base object like in this example ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following method (partially using a SO post I couldn't find now)

```
#Models
class ContentType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Content(models.Model):
    contentType = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,null=True,blank=True)
    ...

class ContentText(Content):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
           self.contentType = ContentType.objects.get(name='ContentText')
        super(ContentText, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ContentRichText(Content):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
           self.contentType = ContentType.objects.get(name='ContentRichText')
        super(ContentRichText, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Models save method is overrided, setting contentType when created.

It's now possible to do things like this :

for content in listContent:
       if(content.contentType.name = "ContentText"):
           #do stuff 
       if(content.contentType.name = "ContentRichText"):
           #do other stuff

Not sure it's really the easiest and cleaner method...

Answer (score 0):

[Django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) is your friend, read [django-model-utils inheritance docs](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager), for your scenario:

```
listContent = Content.objects.all().select_subclasses()

for content in listContent:
    if isinstance( content, ContentText):
        #do stuff
    elif isinstance( content, ContentRichText):
        #do other stuff
```

Also, do you can learn about [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) project to accomplish your requirements.

See [Model inheritance django packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-inheritance/) for a complete list.

Comment: `stock method`? Please, explain.

Comment: I mean included in django